# Calling shell_exec shows weird behavior from php

Tags: java, php, linux, fedora, shell-exec

Following php code works and I get output:

```
<?php

echo 'hello world';
echo shell_exec('ls -la');

?>

// Output
hello worldtotal 2064 drwxrwxrwx. 3 root root 4096 Jul 4 10:26 . drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root 4096 Jul 4 10:17 .. -rw-rw-r--. 1 arun arun 2089447 Jul 3 11:09 cakephp-cakephp-2.3.6-0-gd10df32.zip -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 32 Jun 18 18:01 info.php drwxrwxrwx. 7 arun arun 4096 Jul 3 12:23 nykkos -rw-r--r--. 1 arun arun 76 Jul 4 10:26 test.php
```

The following code does not work:

```
<?php

echo 'hello world';
echo shell_exec("java -jar /var/www/html/nyk/app/webroot/Converter.jar $id");

?>
```

It just shows a blank white screen. Even the simple java -version when used in the above php code gives a blank screen. Even the 'hello world' does not get printed.

Whereas the java commands discussed above work without any issues from terminal. My OS is fedora.

What is the reason behind this strange behaviour and how can I overcome the same?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Seems like a permissions issue.

Comment: no..permission is 777

Comment: also the basic java commands are not working where as it works from terminal. If it has permission issues it should also not work from terminal

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem using MAMP on OSX. I think that it should be the same issue. Try open the file envvars that in MAC is on MAMP/Library/bin/envvars. Try to comment the four lines of if and else. this will looks like:

```
#if test "x$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" != "x" ; then
#  DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
#else
#  DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib"
```

Don't forget to reset Apache.
It works fine for me! I hope that you can enjoy it. Good Lucky!